# Making a jagged array in java, error: ' ] ' expected

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm doing an assignment for an intro Java course. According to Jgrasp, Java really wants to see a `]` where ever I specify the number of elements in my array.  Here is my code for my array:

```
//makes an two dimensional global string array named "cal" to put events 
//in and populate a calendar program

public static String[][] cal = new String[12][];
cal[0]=new String[31]; 
cal[1]=new String[28];
cal[2]=new String[31];
cal[3]=new String[30]; 
cal[4]=new String[31];
cal[5]=new String[30]; 
cal[6]=new String[31]; 
cal[7]=new String[31];
cal[8]=new String[30]; 
cal[9]=new String[31]; 
cal[10]=new String[30];
cal[11]=new String[31];
```

According to my text book , this is the correct format for a jagged array, but Jgrasp is saying all the numbers within square brackets are where java expects an extra close bracket. Help?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What do you mean by: *"java really wants to see a ']' "*?

Comment: What line number do you get the error on, and what code is on that line?

Comment: Please also show us the code the comes before this, like the class declaration and all fields.  You may have messed up the code before this code, and the compiler just dies here because it can't figure out the previous code.

Comment: Before posting your errors on SO. Please try to google the exact syntax of something. [how to create jagged array in java](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20create%20jagged%20array%20in%20java&oq=how%20to%20make%20jagged%20array%20in&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.11862j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initializing `static` member outside any `static` block or method body.

Use `static` block to initialize it.

```
public static String[][] cal = new String[12][];
static
{
    cal [0]=new String[31]; 
    cal [1]=new String[28];
    cal [2]=new String[31];
    cal [3]=new String[30]; 
    cal [4]=new String[31];
    cal [5]=new String[30]; 
    cal [6]=new String[31]; 
    cal [7]=new String[31];
    cal [8]=new String[30]; 
    cal [9]=new String[31]; 
    cal [10]=new String[30];
    cal [11]=new String[31];
}
```

See it working [here](https://ideone.com/ezcpJq)

Answer (score 0):

A static member can't be initialized within a nonstatic scope (block or method). You can declare the String as nonstatic and initialize within a nonstatic block.

```
public String[][] cal = new String[12][];
{
    cal [0]=new String[31]; 
    cal [1]=new String[28];
    cal [2]=new String[31];
    cal [3]=new String[30]; 
    cal [4]=new String[31];
    cal [5]=new String[30]; 
    cal [6]=new String[31]; 
    cal [7]=new String[31];
    cal [8]=new String[30]; 
    cal [9]=new String[31]; 
    cal [10]=new String[30];
    cal [11]=new String[31];
}
```

or You can initialize it within main method or any static method.

```
public static String[][] cal = new String[12][];
    public static void main(String args[]){
    cal [0]=new String[31]; 
    cal [1]=new String[28];
    cal [2]=new String[31];
    cal [3]=new String[30]; 
    cal [4]=new String[31];
    cal [5]=new String[30]; 
    cal [6]=new String[31]; 
    cal [7]=new String[31];
    cal [8]=new String[30]; 
    cal [9]=new String[31]; 
    cal [10]=new String[30];
    cal [11]=new String[31];
  }
```

or You can initialize it within a static block

```
 public static String[][] cal = new String[12][];
static
{
    cal [0]=new String[31]; 
    cal [1]=new String[28];
    cal [2]=new String[31];
    cal [3]=new String[30]; 
    cal [4]=new String[31];
    cal [5]=new String[30]; 
    cal [6]=new String[31]; 
    cal [7]=new String[31];
    cal [8]=new String[30]; 
    cal [9]=new String[31]; 
    cal [10]=new String[30];
    cal [11]=new String[31];
}
```